# Rust Linking with link failed (code 1120) despite correct VC++ installation

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

While Hello world compiles fine, this program gives me error 1120 failed to link with link

This is my rustc -Vv:

```
rustc 1.42.0 (b8cedc004 2020-03-09)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: b8cedc00407a4c56a3bda1ed605c6fc166655447
commit-date: 2020-03-09
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.42.0
LLVM version: 9.0
```

Environment Variables PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

This code runs FINE

```
extern crate stdweb;

mod canvas;
mod direction;

use canvas::Canvas;

pub fn main() {
    println!("Hello World");
}
```

This code gives me the error

```
extern crate stdweb;

mod canvas;
mod direction;

use canvas::Canvas;

pub fn main() {
    //THIS GIVES ERROR 1120 failed linking with link

    stdweb::initialize();

    let canvas = Canvas::new("#canvas", 20, 20);

    canvas.draw(5,5,"red");

    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Isn't `stdweb` a pure webassembly crate? If so you can only use it in a wasm target, not a native target.

Comment: Did you install Rust with `rustup`? Did you compile with `cargo build`?

Answer (score 0):

FIX:

I should have used the "cargo web" tool to compile